# How to pass an array as argument in odeint to differentiate an ODE?

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I have 3 coupled differential equations that have a variable in common which is supposed to have different values at a different instance of time.
For example, if the time ranges from 0 to 50 (seconds) then the variable `temperature` should also increase/increase from 20 to 70. For every timestep, a corresponding value from my temperature array should be used. The length of my timestamp and temperature array will be the same.

I have tried passing an array in the arguments parameter in odeint function but it throws error

```
temp = np.linspace(20,30, 1000)
        
solution = odeint(fermentation_model, y0, t, args=(temp,))

# Define the ODE system
def fermentation_model(y, t, T):
    print("I am insude")
    # Define the parameters
    mu_max = 0.5 # maximum specific growth rate at optimal temperature
    T_opt = 37 # optimal temperature for growth
    Q_max = 0.1 # maximum specific substrate uptake rate at optimal temperature
    K_m = 0.01 # Michaelis-Menten constant for substrate uptake at optimal temperature
    P_ep = 0.05 # enzyme synthesis rate at optimal temperature
    P_delta = 0.01 # enzyme degradation rate at optimal temperature
    E_max = 0.01 # maximum enzyme concentration
    T_min = 20 # minimum allowable temperature
    T_max = 50 # maximum allowable temperature

    # Calculate the temperature-dependent parameters
    mu = mu_max * np.exp(-0.5 * ((T - T_opt) / T_opt)**2) # maximum specific growth rate
    Q = Q_max * np.exp(-0.5 * ((T - T_opt) / T_opt)**2) # maximum specific substrate uptake rate
    K = K_m * np.exp(0.2 * ((T - T_opt) / T_opt)**2) # Michaelis-Menten constant
    P_e = P_ep * np.exp(-0.1 * ((T - T_opt) / T_opt)**2) # enzyme synthesis rate
    P_d = P_delta * np.exp(0.1 * ((T - T_opt) / T_opt)**2) # enzyme degradation rate
    E = y[2] / (1 + y[2] / E_max) # fraction of enzyme in active form

    # Define the ODEs
    dNdt = mu * y[0] # growth of cells
    dSdt = -Q * E * y[1] / (K + y[1]) * y[0] # consumption of substrate
    dEdt = P_e * y[0] - P_d * y[2] # change in enzyme concentration
 return [dNdt, dSdt, dEdt]
```

I went through the documentation of ODEINT but could not find anything that could help me solve it.

How can I differential my equations with a variable that will keep changeing its value with time?
I am open to use other differentiation functions as well.

Comment: In the model function, how do you extract the temperature for the time argument from the array?

Comment: Without code for `fermentation_model` we can't help you.

Comment: `odeint` passes that `temp` array to your function as is.  It's not iterating on it.  It's up to your function to something intelligent with it.

Comment: @LutzLehmann my time array is of lenth 1000 where the timesteps are between values 0 to 48 and I have 1000 values of temperatures that are between 20 to 30. As the lengths of both the arrays are same I would want the program to choose the same index value from both the arrays. Ex. in the first loop, timestep = 0.1 and temperature = 20. these 2 values belong to the first index of both the arrays, similarly in the next loop the corresponding values from both the arrays should be used. Does that make sense?

Comment: The ODE or model function is almost never evaluated at the times of the time array, the output values there get interpolated from the internal step, "overshoot and interpolate". This means you need to convert the discrete function table into an actual continuous function. This process is generally known as "interpolation".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving ODEs with parameters from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76456191/solving-odes-with-parameters-from-an-array)