# Solving ODEs with parameters from an array

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations, coefficients

I've already solved these 2 differential equations with constant coefficients for `ne`, `Zeff` and `Epar` using `odeint` but now I want to solve them passing values at each time step for the coefficients from an array. How can this be done?

```
def f(Q, t):
    # constants
    ne=5E19
    ln=17
    permit=8.8542E-12
    m_e=9.1094E-31
    c=2.9979E8
    e=1.6E-19
    B0=6
    R0=0.935
    Zeff=3
    Epar=0.2
    Er=(e**3*ne*ln)/(4*np.pi*permit**2*m_e*c**2)
    D = Epar/Er
    alpha = 1+Zeff
    Fgy = (2*permit*B0**2)/(3*ne*m_e*ln)
    Fgc = Fgy*((m_e*c)/(e*B0*R0))**2
    nur=ne*e**4*ln/(4*np.pi*permit**2*m_e**2*c**3)
    

    # assign each ODE to a vector element
    qp, q = Q
    gamma=(1+q**2)**(1/2)
    qpp2=q**2-qp**2
    # define each ODE
    dqpdt = (D-gamma*(gamma+alpha)*qp/(q**3)-(Fgc+Fgy*qpp2/q**4)*gamma**4*(((gamma**2)-1)**(1/2)/gamma)**3*qp/q)*nur
    dqdt = (D*qp/q-gamma**2/q**2-(Fgc+Fgy*qpp2/q**4)*gamma**4*(((gamma**2)-1)**(1/2)/gamma)**3)*nur

    return [dqpdt,dqdt]
```

I've tried using `args`and `odeint` but with the simulation time equal to the time step but unsuccesfully.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done because you have no control over the time steps used in the integration. You only control the time steps for the output, the values there get interpolated from the internal integration steps (`odeint` does this "conceptually" backwards, it tries to interpolate the next output value, and if that is not possible advances the internal step until it is possible. This gives one output value per call of the underlying Fortran routine, with a variable number, possibly zero, of internal steps).

Thus if you want time-dependent parameters, you need to pass them as time-dependent functions, so that the integrator can find the parameters for any time in the integration interval. If the parameters are given as a function table, you have to provide the best guess for a time-continuous function (value-continuous is optional, zero-hold or step functions are possible), this process is called interpolation. Numpy and scipy provide several procedures for different interpolation methods.